# Event listener only attaches to the last entry in the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps), also comes with the fiddle, I want to attach event listener to each marker object. The way it is done is that I loop through my Json object, and while looping attach event handler to each marker object. I'm doing the exact thing but with Json and not XML. The code is mostly same, except how indexing happens. Instead of `downloadURL`, I use `getJSON` from jquery. For instance:

```
const arr = json; 
for (var r of arr){
    id = r.id;
    .....
    ..... 
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
              });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);


}
```

I have debugged this part and ensured that the objects (`id`, `address`) are all correct. The problem is that when I click on any marker, event listener seems to be only attaching to the last entry in the loop. It seems to be working with XML, why is not working with Json format ?

Comment: where is the event listener? perhaps rather than using a global variable to hold `id` you should do something like `let id = r.id;`

Comment: I've modified my question. Perhaps it may answer your question. It is the exact same as the tutorial. `let` does not seem to help.

Comment: use `let marker =` instead of `var marker =`

Answer (score -1):

Had to use `let` instead of `var`. Thanks to [jaromanda-x](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x).